# how to add a button in the snap page of windows 8 app development?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have done a windows 8 app called bmi calculator which I want to upload in the store but it says that I have to add snap tool to it. I don't know how to add a textbox or a button in a snapped page

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [SnapView](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/walkthrough-implementing)?